# I can not get authorized account's id(primary key) for profile page view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm preparing a homework, in the project i need to show every user their profile pages when they click the profile button.But I cant reach authorized person's id from the database.When I manually insert id value, it shows correctly but when i click profile button it's giving "source cant found" error.

I tried to fix routes.

```
 public class ProfileController : Controller
 {
    datingDbEntities db = new datingDbEntities();

    [Authorize]
    [ Route( "Profile/Profil/{id}" ) ]

    public ActionResult Profil(int? id)
    {
        userAcc user = db.userAcc.Find(id);
        return View(user);
    }
  }
```

This is the controller side.

```
@using datingo.Models.EntityFramework
@model userAcc

<tr>
        <td>@Model.userId </td>
        <td>@Model.userName </td>
<tr>
```

this is the .cshtml side.

```
namespace datingo.Models.EntityFramework
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class userAcc
  {


     public int userId { get; set; }
     public string userName { get; set; }
     public string userPw { get; set; }
     public string userMail { get; set; }
     public Nullable<bool> userGender { get; set; }
     public string userAd { get; set; }
     public string userSoyad { get; set; }
     public Nullable<int> userBoy { get; set; }
     public Nullable<int> userKilo { get; set; }
     public string userHair { get; set; }
     public string userEye { get; set; }
     public string userCountry { get; set; }
     public string userFavTeam { get; set; }
     public string userBurc { get; set; }
     public string userFavMusic { get; set; }
     public string userFavFilm { get; set; }
     public string userMeslek { get; set; }
     public string userEgitim { get; set; }
     public byte[] userPhoto { get; set; }

 }
}
```

this is the entity side model class, generated from database first model

by the way in nav bar the linking is like    "/Profile/Profil"

```
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/Profile/Profil">Profile</a>
              </li>
```

i except the profile button output as Profile/Profil/"authorizeduserid"

by the way in my "Model" folder there is one more folder named as "Entity Framework".My EF in that folder.

Comment: where is the button code?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad edited

Comment: i tried to change navbar linking as "Profile/Profil/@Model.userId" , i added the needed namespace and @model datingo.Models.EntityFramework.userAcc, after that i get the "...Model.get returned null" error